# Set system attribute only if if precondition is given c#

Tags: c#, attributes

I like to add a custom attribute to a class.

But this custom attribute should only be active if a precondition is given.

Code snippet:

```
[CustomAtt]
public class MyClass
{
     //with all methods
}
```

The `CustomAttribute` should only be active if an if block is `true`.

e.g.

```
public class AnyClass
{
    public bool CheckPrecon()
    {
       if (/* condition */)
       {
          return true;
       }

       return false;
    }
}
```

Only if `CheckPrecon()` is `true` the custom attribute `[CustomAtt]` should be active.

Is there any chance to do this in c#?

Comment: Only if the precondition is known at compile-time. This sounds like an XY problem: what issue are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @canton7 try to give `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]` this attribute only if the user with the mail ast.most@domain.com is logged in my asp.net web app

Comment: You could make a class that inherits it and has the attribute.

Comment: or exists a way to check this precon before executing all methods in the class? Because I think if I have a class with 100 methods I can not add if statement to all methods to check the precon.

Comment: @kavob15078 Right, and why?

Comment: @canton7 what do you mean :)

Comment: Can you give a larger example of what problem you're trying to solve? Why are you trying to decorate a class with `[AttributeUsage...]` only if a particular user is logged in? What's the problem you're ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: I like to protect my controller. At the moment I differentiate between loged in users and not logged in users. But I like to have the chance to have also controllers which can be used only of user with the id 1231. And I check the user id in the if statement. If its true => the user can access to controller.

Comment: Sounds like you want role-based authorization? All logged-in users have a particular role, but user 1234 has an additional, more privileged role. Your controllers which only user 1234 can access require this more privileged role

Comment: How I can set privileged role for this user in school/work organization?

Comment: [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0). "*How these roles are created and managed depends on the backing store of the authorization process*", so it rather depends on what backing store you're using, which you haven't shared